# Can you offer flexible PTO to some but not all employees

Tags: job-offer, hiring-process, recruitment, human-resources, company-culture

We seriously need to change our policy we are in California so laws are pretty strict here. I am pushing to offer a flexible policy for all employees. Partners want to designate it to employees who have been here for 2+ years. Anyone have experience implementing something similar. I believe it is easier to give everyone the freedom and flexibility for many reasons.

Comment: If this is policy rather than guaranteed in the contract and thus a matter of law, I can't see any reason they couldn't make that requirement. New hires are not a legally protected class.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't even understand what you are asking? First, what exactly is the policy you want to implement around PTO? Secondly, what is your goal? Just asking for "experiences" is much too vague and thus off-topic. Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: Unless there is local legislation or an enterprise/union agreement, then any company can offer any remuneration they like to any individual they employ.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's very reasonable to limit PTO to employees with some seniority.

As the saying goes, "give someone a hand, and they take the arm".

Just giving flexible PTO to everyone, even those who haven't demonstrated the responsibility and sensibility necessarily for longevity at your firm is calling for trouble.